# I cannot input object through post route, instead only get undefined in node js

Tags: javascript, ejs

i am trying to pass a comment and associate comment(object with name and author) to object of campground.but while i try to pass it through post route it will show undefined.

error occur here

```
    //add a new comment in campground
   app.post('/campgrounds/:id/comments',function(req,res){
//find campground with id
Campground.findById(req.params.id,function(err,campground){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
        res.redirect('/campgrounds/');
    }else{
        console.log(req.body.comments)
    }
})
//create comment 
//associate created comment to campground
//redirect to show page
```

})

this is comment form

```
    <%-include('../partials/header')-%>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div style="width: 40%; margin: 50px auto;">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Add a new comment to <%=campground.name%> </h1>
        <form action="/campgrounds/<%-campground._id %>/comments" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group"> 
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comments[text]" placeholder='Text'>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comments[author]" placeholder="Author">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
     </div>
  </div>
```

```
    <%-include('../partials/footer')-%>
```

result is shown as undefined despite a previous post route works fine. it is not a issue with body parser .help